# Compatability of GADM v4.0 with 4.1

Tags: gadm, brazil

Is there a key or documentation for linking administrative divisions from version 4.0 with version 4.1, as well as documentation of the sources that are used for each version of the data? I'm specifically working with Brazilian level 2 administrative divisions, and some of my data have keys linking them to admin divisions from GADM 4.0 while others are linked to 4.1 divisions.